# Laravel: Relation between three model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm doing a project where every **user** can be assigned in a designation.

I did my work by using three model: **User**, **Designation** & **UsersDesignation**

The table structures are:

```
User:
id      name        email       password
---     -----       -----       --------
1       User 1      u1@em.com   kjasdkfjla
2       User 2      u2@em.com   fksdjfghal
3       User 3      u3@em.com   ghhaljaljl

Designation:
id      name
---     -----
1       Faculty
2       Lecturer
3       Lab Instructor

UsersDesignation:
id      userId      designationId
---     ------      -------------
1       1           2
2       2           1
3       3           3
```

But I'm facing difficulty to get the `designation` of user from `user` object by establishing relationship.

I've tried in my Model so far:

```
User(model):
public function userDesignation()
{
    $this->hasOne('App\UsersDesignation', 'id', 'userId');
}

UserDesignation(model):
public function user()
{
    $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'userId', 'id');
}
public function designation()
{
    $this->belongsTo('App\Designation', 'designationId', 'id');
}
```

Actually I want to show the `user profiles` from `user` model with his/her `designation`. But the above way didn't work. I've no idea how to make this relation.

This is my view file:

```
<div>
    {{ $user->userDesignation->designationId }}
</div>
```

The error I get every time

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) App\User::userDesignation must return a
>   relationship instance. (View:
>   ....\resources\views\profiles\show.blade.php)

I badly need this help!

Comment: Does a user only have 1 possible destination?

Answer (score 3):

If a User can only have 1 possible designation, you don't need a pivot table(UsersDesignation table).

Just put a **designation_id** in the **users** table and use the belongsTo and hasMany relationships.

**User**

```
public function designation()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Designation');
}
```

**Designation**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

Comment: hasOne() and not hasMany() relationship

Comment: Not if a designation can have multiple users.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need use a relationship [many to many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

Example:

Table structures:

```
users:
id
name
email
password

designations:
id
name

designation_user
id
designation_id
user_id
```

Your model relationships

**App\User**:

```
public function designations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Designation');
}
```

**App\Designation**:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

To get the user's designations your call should look like this:

```
<div>
    @foreach($user->designations()->get() as $designation)
        {{ $designation->name }}
    @endforeach
</div>
```